# a little question of action based on struts2

Tags: spring, struts2

friends! I am learning struts2 framework by vaannila's [Struts 2 Spring Integration](http://www.vaannila.com/struts-2/struts-2-example/struts-2-spring-plugin-integration-1.html)
,In running the application, I am confused by the success.jsp ,part of the file like below:

> `<body>`
>
> ```
>   ${message}
> ```
>
> `</body>`

after step by step buding followed the tutorial, when tomcat fire up, the brower shows
just what lies in  of success.jsp **${message}**  .But logically it should indicate
Spring's powerful Dependency Injection feature. I checked the configuration like:

- The action (here is **helloWorld.action**)
- The class really do what action requires (here is **HelloWorld.java**)
- the link between action and working class

  applicationContext.xml do configured spring bean like

  ```
    <bean id="helloWorldClass" class="com.vaannila.HelloWorld" >
      <property name="message" value="Hello World!" />
    </bean>
  ```

  struts.xml do named a action called `helloWolrd` for referring to the bean `helloWorldClass` which defined in applicationContext.xml
  like:

  > ```
  >  <action name="helloWorld" class="helloWorldClass">
  >        <result name="SUCCESS">/success.jsp</result>
  >  </action>
  > ```

but it seemed that the bean property for showing DependancyInjection which defined in applicationcontext.xml DID NOT WORK, why?

Comment: The **[downloadable source](http://www.vaannila.com/examples/struts2/src/Struts2Example14.zip)** is worked properly.

Comment: If you are following the tutorial exactly then run a diff on the files (from the downloadable source provided by Ischin).

Comment: friend Quaternion, you give a good idea:) friend Ischin should be right, but if you changed the message in bean `helloWorldClass` it seems not works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

${message} should work. Looks like your jsp is unable to parse EL. Check first if your jsp can parse EL. Try with ${1+2}. If it prints directly on the browser, add the following on the top of your jsp page.

```
<%@ page isELIgnored="false"%>
```

You can also want to use this !

```
<s:property value="message"/>
```

Comment: `${ }` is fine and have better performance than `<s:property />`. I'm never use `<s:property />` unless dealing with `type conversion` and `OGNL`.

Comment: using <s:property /> gives you much flexibility while escaping HTML tags. And also, ${} will throw exception if the property is null. but <s:property /> will print nothing.

Comment: Need to clarify your misleading : `${ }` would not throw exception if `property` is not exist and `${ }` will print nothing if value of `property` is null. See also : **[Performance Tuning](http://struts.apache.org/2.2.3/docs/performance-tuning.html)**

Comment: @lschin thanks a lot for clarifying the misleading. You forced me to test what I have commented and found that you are right!!!

Comment: Tusar, thanks! your solution works:) I will keep an eye on the mechanism of this. and thanks every else friends :)

Answer (score 1):

Are the setters in place in your Action  - ie setMessage(String) ??

If yes, see if the spring actually calls it at any time - use debugger inside this method.

Post the files if all of this is true ?

---

PS - Is the setup for Spring complete ? Like you have Spring config file defined, web.xml does have the Spring context listener in it and don't forget to push in the Spring jar in you web app.

Answer (score 0):

does "`message`" has setter and getter method? It has to be exactly `setMessage` and `getMessage`

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are trying to mix two things over here.

1. Spring dependency injection  AND
2. JSP scope variables

The `${message}` will try to look for variable 'message' in various scope beginning from PageScope right up to applictionScope.

where as  doing

```
<bean id="helloWorldClass" class="com.vaannila.HelloWorld" >
    <property name="message" value="Hello World!" />
  </bean>
```

will inject a property in `com.vaannila.HelloWorld` instance. This will not be available to jsp. For that you need to put this variable in some scope from action class (in request,session or application).

Comment: In the case of S2, `${}` will actually look in the S2 value stack first before checking the normal servlet scopes. Your second statement is also largely incorrect; if an action class has an accessible property (public getter in early versions, anything in later versions, including private properties with no accessors) then the value will be available in JSP via EL *or* the S2 tags.

Comment: Can you quote an example to support what you are saying ?

Comment: An example of what? Re: JSP EL, that's how the S2 request wrapper is written. Re: OGNL property access, that's just how OGNL works.

Comment: (I think it might just be that you don't need a getter, the property itself must still be public; OGNL changed to allow property access without public getters.)

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to add

```
<constant name="struts.objectFactory" value="spring" />
```

to your struts.xml config to make the spring integration work properly.

```
<struts>
    <constant name="struts.objectFactory" value="spring" />
    ...
</struts>
```